# css text align vertically in responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment

I have a header in a div like this

[image]

When I make the broswer small it looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

how do I do that?

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <h4>ALongText LikeThisOne</h4>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    border:1px red solid;
    height:60px;
}

.wrapper h4{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cBxt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try `transform` property:

```
.wrapper h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cBxt/6/)**

Comment: ok, thanks for the info but I dont need to care about ie8 in this project, thanks god!

Answer (score 2):

Use vertical-align, text-align along with display css properties to render the text within the Div vertically and horizontally center.

```
.wrapper{
 border:1px red solid;
 height:60px;
 display: table;
}

.wrapper h4{
  margin-top: 0;   
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4cBxt/2/

Comment: Thanks but now you changed the width of the wrapper. It must be 100% wide